# ItemsControl won't re-render after showing a Popup on it

Tags: wpf, itemscontrol

I have an **ItemsControl** on a Window one of the column of which contains a simple very narrow StackPanel that serves just as a Target for a **Popup** which is shown under certain circumstances.

After the has been shown and the user has been informed about something, the user closes this **Popup** by means of a button (the command bound to this button just sets the property of the view model to which **Popup.IsOpen** is bound to **false**).

The **Popup** closes, but its image remains imprinted on the **ItemsControl** until it is scrolled or another window overlaps it.

How to *repaint* the **ItemsControl** after the **Popup** has been closed?

Code:

1) ItemsControl

```
<ScrollViewer ...>
  <ItemsControl x:Name="ux_List" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource Lib_ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=TemplateInfos,Mode=OneWay}" AlternationCount="2" ... />
```

2) Item template

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="Lib_ItemTemplate">
  <Grid x:Name="grid">
...
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
       <Popup IsOpen="{Binding Path=HasError,Mode=OneWay}">
          <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=ErrorContext, Mode=OneWay}"
```

and there's a close button inside the presenter in the last line of the snippet above:

```
<Button ... Command="{TemplateBinding CloseButtonCommand}" />
```

A command is bound to this button implemented like this:

```
private void OnCloseErrorMessageCommand()
{
    HasError = false;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to post a picture of what you mean? Or perhaps some code? I think Popups get drawn at a different layer than the UI layer, so repainting the ItemsControl might not do anything

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. When I close the popup everything is closed nicely.
Can you show us your markup?

But something like this should work:

<Popup Closed="myPopup_Closed" ...

    private void myPopup_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      myItemsControl.InvalidateVisual();
    }

Comment: I've never seen a Popup in a DataTemplate, and to me it doesn't look like being a valid approach, but i'm not sure. What do the others say?

Comment: I've got the same problem but not in an ItemsControl. The answer below that uses the native call is the only answer that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my workground:

On Control's parent window:

```
    public IntPtr Hwnd { get; set; }
    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
        IntPtr hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        this.Hwnd = hwnd;
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        if (Hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Hwnd");
        InvalidateRect(this.Hwnd, IntPtr.Zero, true);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
    public static extern bool InvalidateRect(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr rect, bool erase);
```

After Popup closed,Call Refresh() method.

Comment: I tried everything I could think of in managed code, but the popup wasn't erased after it was closed. This solution, using a native call, did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

When the popup closes, what happens if you set Visibility = Collapsed?  Seems like that would pretty well remove it from view completely.

Otherwise I know of no way to rerender a single item and the ItemsControl.Refresh method will reload all of your items (and usually results in display goofyness (items disappear and reappear, animations reset, etc).

Comment: 1) I tried to set the Visibility property to Collapsed (along with IsOpen) by means of data binding - the result is the same

2) I'm not aware of the ItemsControl.Refresh() method. Does it really exist?

Comment: I know that Listbox.Items.Refresh exists as well as other incarnations of ItemsControl.  It really just tells the Items control to dispose of the drawn items, requery the items collection and redraw them.

Comment: Just to be sure, when you change the IsOpen property, *something* is happening visually right?  If not, do you have INotifyPropertyChanged implemented?

Comment: Yes, something is happening - the Popup (containing a message and a button that closes it) _logically_ goes away, but its image remains on the ItemsControl (when I'm pointing the mouse at the Close button, it's not changing its form to the _Hand_ view).
INotifyPropertyChanged is implemented.

Comment: When you tried collapsing it, did you try collapsing it first and then closing it?  That *should* make it seem to disappear and then close...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess what prevents your ItemsControl from redrawing after the Popup has closed. This should usually not happen.

One thing you can always do is to call [InvalidateVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatevisual.aspx) or [InvalidateArrange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatearrange.aspx) on the ItemsControl. This forces a complete new layout/rendering cycle.

Comment: To re-render the ItemsControl I added a handler to the GotFocus event (which executes after the Popup closes and the window that hosts the ItemsControl gets focus). In this handler I called the UpdateLayout() method of the ItemsControl, but the footprint of the Popup remained.

Comment: Oh, i've confused UpdateLayout and InvalidateVisual and updated my answer. Thanks SvenG and sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I tried them all in the GotFocus code-behind handler: UpdateLayout, InvalidateVisual, and InvalidateArrange - unfortunately none of them helped to re-render the ItemsControl

Comment: Ok, then i'll refer to Rachels comment to your question about Popups getting drawn in a different layer than the UI layer. Please post some code that shows how your popup is created and how it gets on screen.